# When will Postgres's full text search supports phrase match and proximity match?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

As of Postgres 8.4 the database fts does not support exact phrase match, nor does it support proximity match if given 2 terms. For example, there is no way to tell Postgres to match on content that have word #1 which is in a specified proximity of word #2. Any one know the plan of Postgres and possibly which version will phrase and proximity match be supported?

Comment: The PostgreSQL project doesn't have a roadmap.  Things get done on the basis of who actually decides to do the work.  So no idea, no possible answer.

Answer (score 4):

PostgreSQL 9.6 text search supports phrases now

```
select
  *
from (values
  ('i heart new york'),
  ('i hate york new')
) docs(body)
where
  to_tsvector(body) @@ phraseto_tsquery('new york')

(1 row retrieved)
```

or by distance between words:

```
-- a distance of exactly 2 "hops" between "quick" and "fox"
select
  *
from (values
  ('the quick brown fox'),
  ('quick brown cute fox')
) docs(body)
where
  to_tsvector(body) @@ to_tsquery('quick <2> fox') 

(1 row retrieved)
```

Comment: The quest is about Proximity search, for example: Is the word 'the' and the word 'fox' is less than 2 words apart?

Comment: Can someone explain me why would someone want proximity search? I would like PostgreSQL to rank documents where keywords are closer higher, but why would I want the actual answer to how close they were?

Comment: You can use it as a fallback when phrase match does not yield results. For instance, given the doc `hip hop is music`, if you search for `"hip hop music"` it does not match, but if you search for `hip <1> hop <1> music` it will match and is still a phrase search, approximate phrase. It also depends if you have a block list etc... but that is the idea.

Answer (score 2):

http://linuxgazette.net/164/sephton.html

`<snip>`

**Search Vectors**

How does one turn document content into an array of lexemes using the parser and dictionaries? How does one match a search criterion ti body text? PostgreSQL provides a number of functions to do this. The first one we will look at is to_tsvector().

A tsvector is an internal data type containing an array of lexemes with position information. The lexeme positions are used when searching, to **rank the search result based on proximity** and other information. One may control the ranking by labelling the different portions which make up the search document content, for example the title, body and abstract **may be weighted differently during search** by labelling these sections differently. The section labels, quite simply A,B,C & D, are associated with the tsvector at the time it is created, but the weight modifiers associated with those labels may be controlled after the fact.

`</snip>`

For full-phrase searching, [see here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489617/how-do-you-do-phrase-based-full-text-search-in-postgres-that-takes-advantage-of-t)

The Postgresql website does not have a roadmap.  Instead, you are referred to the [Open Issues page.](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_9.0_Open_Items)  At the moment, this page makes no mention of full-phrase searching.

Comment: So the short answer is that there is no proximity match (as in NEAR() in Oracle) and there's is no efficient phrase matching for Postgres :(

Comment: Is that what I said?  If you're looking for the short path, i.e. a keyword in the SQL language, then no.  But that doesn't mean you can't do it with the tools outlined in the article.

Comment: The article mentions 'phrase search' needs a 'like' (or 'ilike') operator to scan through the limited result set which may be expensive. What other tools in particular that I may overlook?