# How can I make a case insensitive TypeORM query in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am attempting to create a basic search for my application. I have a `GET` route that looks like this:

```
https://my-api.com/v1/organizations

-OR-

https://my-api.com/v1/organizations?name=Stark
```

I've followed several tutorials, and have tried (with no luck) ILIKE or ILike.

In my database (Postgres), my table is named `organizations` and it has one row:

```
name
Stark Industries
```

Using the following query in my repository file works if I search the same case that is stored in the database: `Stark`.

```
...
const { name } = getOrganizationsFilterDto;

const query = await this.createQueryBuilder('organizations');

if (name) {
    query.andWhere('LOWER(organizations.name) LIKE LOWER(:name)', {
        name: `%${name}%`,
    });
}

return await query.getMany();
```

If I search `STARK` (all uppercase). I do not get any results back. `[]`.
How can I update my query so that `STARK` or `Stark` or `stark` or `sTArk` would work?

Comment: I think you are searching for full text search: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-textsearch.html. Btw, fixing that query to be sth like: `query.andWhere(\`to_tsvector('simple', name) @@ to_tsquery('simple', :name)`, { name: `${name}:*\` }).getMany()`. For further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622021/suggest-like-google-with-postgresql-trigrams-and-full-text-search

Comment: please add the missing backtick, I have bad writing with escaping those characters @Damon

Comment: another option is `if (name) {
    query.andWhere('LOWER(organizations.name) LIKE :lowerName', {
        lowerName: `%${name.toLowerCase()}%`,
    });
}