# PostgreSQL prevent non-matching tsqueries from matching tsvector

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Given the following query:

```
select to_tsvector('fat cat ate rat') @@ plainto_tsquery('cats ate');
```

This query will return true as a result. Now, what if I don't want "cats" to also match the word "cat", is there any way I can prevent this?

Also, is there any way I can make sure that the tsquery matches the entire string in that particular order (e.g. the "cats ate" is counted as a single token rather than two). At the moment the following query will also match:

```
select to_tsvector('fat cat ate rat') @@ plainto_tsquery('ate cats');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cat` matching `cats` is due to english stemming, english being probably your default text search configuration. See the result of `show default_text_search_config` to be sure.

It can be avoided by using the `simple` configuration. Try the function calls with explicit text configurations:

```
select to_tsvector('simple', 'fat cat ate rat') @@ plainto_tsquery('simple', 'cats ate');
```

Or change it with:

```
set default_text_search_config='simple';
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I was looking into alternative dictionaries, but the documentation was not really clear on what (other) dictionaries were available and what their properties were. I will definitely try this dictionary.

Comment: Do you know how to increase precision of the matching further by making 'fat cat' count as a single token rather  than two?

Comment: @invictus: I don't see how the parser could be tweaked to group words. If you want phrase search it's not implemented but that can be worked around more or less, see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489617).