# Does postgreSQL support fulltext search on a phrase

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Let's say I want to search "Mad Max" and I only want results wherein 'Max' follows 'Mad'. That is:

```
Mad Max is a good movie. ==> matched!
Max is not mad in the movie. ===> not matched.
```

It looks like it is something not mentioned in the documents. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Support for phrase search was added with the just released version 9.6: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-9-6.html  see also here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25007405/330315

Comment: That's great! I was looking at the 9.5 docs. Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

For later reference.

```
SELECT to_tsvector('fatal error') @@ to_tsquery('fatal <-> error');
 ?column? 
----------
 t

SELECT to_tsvector('error is not fatal') @@ to_tsquery('fatal <-> error');
 ?column? 
----------
 f
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/textsearch-intro.html#TEXTSEARCH-MATCHING